# Contrast color suggestions needed

Tags: color, contrast

I have an element in each of the three different rows indicating their intital state. I need color suggestions for change in state of this element (as indicated in the image below). I have already suggested two colors but they appear to be same on other screens due to resolution issues. How can I get the right color to show the state change. [image]

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Color CC](https://color.adobe.com) (which was named Kuler in the past) may help you if you already got an idea of what you want, but also if you dont ; there is many color scheme [there](https://color.adobe.com/fr/explore/newest/).

This is for a computer/web tool, right ? I dont think the resolution can blend color as you say. It may be the color profile.

The color scheme in the image look great. I propose an [alternative](https://color.adobe.com/fr/Graphic-Design---Tempo-color-theme-8454339/), with the same color tones, but imo, with more possibilities. Hexa from left to right : #DF423A, #FFFFFF, #CACACA, #452828, #454545.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mijer, welcome. would you mind adding the images behind the links in your answer? Link rot is a big issue and if that link becomes invalid your answer would be less useful. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thank you for your welcome Luciano. Of course I can, and I will.